# 2Checkout Payment integration with Odoo

Tags: odoo

How to use the 2Checkout payment integration with Odoo. I have gone through their documentation but i have no idea how to develop the module in odoo to integrate 2checkout.Is there any guideline for that. If there is any examples that would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a guideline for creating custom payment processors, however you can take ones that already exist and replace the processors logic with logic for 2Checkout.

The easiest one is the Ogone module: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/payment_ogone

In fact, you'll find the Odoo developers doing the same thing.  I occasionally saw [an Ogone reference in other payment modules](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/payment_transfer/controllers/main.py#L12) accidentally left in.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Requirement for any payment gateway:

1) Go through the document, where you can find what data are required to
   send in request and what response you will get.
2) Generate the request and send it from your module, you will get
   response.
3) Now, as in odoo every response from the payment gateway is sent to the
   web so to handle you need to design some web template.
4) And in the web controller you can do all the process that you need to do for the order or invoice.

You can do this with the default payment gateway like paypal or Bukaroo available in Odoo.

Hope it will help you.